# How to test business logic in a class

Tags: java, testing

So I have a system that has been broken down into interfaces and implementations to allow mocking etc. That is all great and I can test all the functions. Because everything has an input and output.

Now, my business logic is basically a class that ties this entire system together and specifies how things flow. How can I ensure that actions were taken at a specific point etc?

How can I test this business class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it ties the entire system probably you don't need to unit test it. It seams more an integration test.

Anyway if you need to check that the right sequence of steps is called from your business class you can mock the other classes used from your business class (using libraries like Mockito) and verify only the sequence of calls.

If you need real data to test it this is not a unit test, but an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Test it through TestNG or JUnit parameterized test. Set different variants of combinations of input data as parameters sets. And run the tests.

Comment: Ok, i'll look into that. Cheers.